# How to tell whether you are in a rake task or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have a default scope set in my model.  However, when I call a particular model function from my rake task, I don't want the scope to be in effect.  So, when my model is loaded, how can I tell if it was loaded within a rake task or not.

Comment: There is an answer may be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858230/how-to-detect-whether-my-rails-is-running-in-migration-or-not-in-environment-rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model should never know something like this. If you want your rake task to access your model without the default_scope kicking in, you should look at the [with_exclusive_scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002312) method.

See [this blog post](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/11/18/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-default-scoping) for an example.