# How to check if Rails code is running within a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Is there some easy way to detect it?

I want to skip some code in the envirmonment.rb file when the rake/rails migrations are running.

Comment: What do you mean with "is running in migration"? The question doesn't really make sense. :S

Comment: wow i dont get your question? yea what do u mean?

Comment: I don't known in envirmonment.rb whether my app is running from rake db:migrate or ruby script/server. If it's db:migrate, and i write some db query in envirmonment.rb, rails cannot do migrate because talbe does not exist yet.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had this problem in a legacy application I was maintaining. There were some observers that were interfering with migrations past a certain point, so I disabled them during migration by checking the application name and arguments

```
  # Activate observers that should always be running
  # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer# observers break a migrate from VERSION xxx - disable them for rake db:migrate
unless ( File.basename($0) == "rake" && ARGV.include?("db:migrate") )
  config.active_record.observers = :user_observer
end
```

Incorporating the comment below by @strw667, in Rails 6.1:

```
  # Activate observers that should always be running
  # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer# observers break a migrate from VERSION xxx - disable them for rake db:migrate
unless (File.basename($0) == "rake" &&  Rake.application.top_level_tasks == ["db:migrate")
  config.active_record.observers = :user_observer
end
```

Comment: Great! Works just as well for optional gems that you only need in a rake task, but not in prod (and that may in fact interfere with your local script/server). Example: config.gem 'fsevents' if RAILS_ENV == 'development' && File.basename($0) == "rake"

Comment: Nice. $0 gives you the file name from where application starts. For script/console it is irb ( in jruby it is jirb).

Comment: Now that there are app preloaders like zeus, this trick may not work any more because `$0` may not be "rake" (zeus lets you set aliases).

Comment: It appears that this doesn't work any more since Rails 6.1 due to ARGV not being populated. Anyone know an alternative? c.f: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67124237/how-to-get-argv-options-on-rails-6-1

Comment: In Rails 6.1 you can use `File.basename($0) == "rake" &&  Rake.application.top_level_tasks == ["db:migrate"]`. C.f: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67287175/1852005

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to disable/enable specific code during migrations:

```rb
if !ARGV.include?("db:migrate") )
  config.active_record.observers = :user_observer
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running code that need the DB up to date I would suggest:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connected? # This returns false if the db couldn't be connected to.
&& !ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration? # This checks if a migration needs to run.
```

This will handle if you are running other db: tasks like db:setup.

Comment: This is `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.migration_context.needs_migration?` now. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50810130/2066546

Answer (score -4):

i think if u want to skip, just comment (#) on code.

or many choose on migration rake.

for example : rake db:migrate:up VERSION=2000123232 its mean , only 2000123232_create_article do migration.

or rake db:migrate VERSION=2000123232 mean start from after 2000123232

or rake db:migrate:down VERSION=2000123232

just rake help u can see what u need to rake.

Do you mean that?

Comment: Your answer is hard to understand (poor english) and you're not answering the question.