# How to correctly instantiate a model in plugin init.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, redmine, redmine-plugins

How do you correctly initialize Redmine plugins that need to instantiate a model (read a database record) defined in the plugin itself?

For example, I have a plugin `my_redmine_plugin` which comes with a model `MyPluginModel`. On plugin initialization, I'd like to

- read a record of `MyPluginModel` from DB
- run some initialization code with the record

Given the following code:

```
require 'redmine'

Redmine::Plugin.register :my_redmine_plugin do
  name 'My Redmine Plugin'

  # ...    
end

Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  m = MyPluginModel.find(1)
  run_some_init_code(m)
end
```

It looks like `to_prepare` runs before the migration:

```
$ bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate NAME=my_redmine_plugin

`table_structure': Could not find table 'mypluginmodel' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
...
```

When I comment out the `to_prepare` block during migration, everything works fine. Is there any way to detect the migration process?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `after_initialize` instead of `to_prepare`. This is not a Redmine problem - Rails initialization process has different hooks that are run at different times during startup. See [the API docs](http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Railtie/Configuration/after_initialize) for further information.

Update: thinking about it this might still not help with the migration - you could just rescue from that error in your hook.

Comment: When simply catching the Exception, I'd still have to find a way to detect if it was caused during migration (ignore it) or production (exit with error). Which brings us back to my initial question: How to detect migration?

Comment: @MichaelKrupp see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858230/how-to-detect-whether-my-rails-is-running-in-migration-or-not-in-environment-rb

Comment: @bbozo thank you! Now I at least have a workaround. Though I could imagine running into all sorts of funny edge-cases with this, as some other people already commented on the site you linked.