# NoMethodError: undefined method `needs_migration?' for ActiveRecord::Migrator:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nomethoderror

I'm getting the below error message, not sure how to resolve it. Can anyone help please?

> NoMethodError: undefined method `needs_migration?' for
>   ActiveRecord::Migrator:Class

Here is the config.ru code:

```
require './config/environment'

if ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?
  raise 'Migrations are pending. Run `rake db:migrate` to resolve the issue.'
end

use Rack::MethodOverride

use UsersController
use ArtworkController
run ApplicationController
```

Comment: Share your sample code as well.

Comment: which rails version are you using?

Comment: Hi @Ravi mariya, I'm using Rails 5.1.4

Comment: Ok, then i think this will not work in rails5

Answer (score 14, accepted):

change your code to

```
if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.migration_context.needs_migration?
  raise 'Migrations are pending. Run `rake db:migrate` to resolve the issue.'
end
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Ravi! Much appreciated :)

Comment: What if there is more than 1 connection in ActiveRecord?